# WSSecHeader insertSecurityHeader

Tags: java, xml

Ошибка:

> WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.`

Версия библиотеки `org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:1.6.192`

Код:

```java
private static final String SIMPLE_XML_SOAP = "<soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Envelope>";
InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(SIMPLE_XML_SOAP.getBytes());
SOAPMessage msg2 = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is2);

SOAPEnvelope env2 = msg2.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
System.out.println(env2.getOwnerDocument()); 

WSSecHeader secHeader2 = new WSSecHeader(); 
secHeader2.setMustUnderstand(true);
secHeader2.insertSecurityHeader(env2.getOwnerDocument());
```

Comment: См. [Справка по Markdown - Код и предварительно отформатированный текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)